# Can we print array elements vertically in java ?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
I have learnt in Java that we can set the size of an array manually in 2D array .
```

I am trying to print array elements vertically . 
This code is giving runtime error.
    What is wrong in this code ?

```
public class printingarrayvertically
{
public static void main ( String abc [] )
{
int ar[][] = new int [4][] ; // allocates first element of each row .    
int i ; 
ar[0][0] = 1 ;
ar[1][0] = 2 ;    
ar[2][0] = 3 ;
ar[3][0] = 4 ;

System.out.println("  ARRAY ELEMENTS ARE : \n " );

for (i=0 ; i<=3 ; i++)
{
System.out.println( ar[i][0] ) ;    
}
```

}
}

Comment: When will such questions stop :( :(. This site is filled with more questions of this nature these days.

Comment: `// allocates first element of each row .` no.

Comment: ***1***: You don't get a runtime error. ***2***: When you get an exception, then tell us what it is. ***3***: since you get a NullPointerException, do research about it's meaning and research how to initialize a 2D array correctly. Then you now your answer.

Comment: You didn’t by any chance mean `ar[0] = new int[1];` and so on, did you?

Comment: yes, i meant this .

Answer (score 0):

In the fifth line,

```
int ar[][] = new int [4][];
```

You wrote the 2D array will have 4 rows but you haven`t mentioned about columns.

Comment: please include such suggestions as comment instead of posting as answer